# (HTML Printing) Next <tr> after page-break wont start at top of page

Tags: html, printing, html-table, page-break

I'm using tables with this report, and my problem is that when I use page-break at the bottom of a page to avoid the last row being cut off, the next elements starts at the middle of the next page.

Here is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="1"></td>
    <td class="2"></td>
    <td class="3"></td>
    <td class="4"></td>
</tr>
<tr style="page-break-after: always;"><td colspan="4"></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td class="1"></td>
    <td class="2"></td>
    <td class="3"></td>
    <td class="4"></td>
</tr>
```

please see screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i think you might be using loop to print your report,

always use **`<br>`** **`<hr>`** or **`page-break-after`** outside the loop..

inspect the element from browser, you will get the error msg if any, and you can solve them..

Comment: insted of dwn-voting and firing me back ques, you'd better go ahead and solve his problem, another thing I have suggested him to inspect the element and not to user <br> inside loop.. this is jst "suggestion" nt final ans..